# Noticed a strange UI mix-up in deleted question

Tags: bug, user-interface, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I went to see this question: [can u guys help me with a java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819880/can-u-guys-help-me-with-a-java-project)

[image: preview]

I was surprised to see that the UI is mixed up. Generally the closed should come first and the deleted would be in the next. In this case, it is the opposite. While it is not even deleted by the OP. It has been closed first.

How is this possible?

Comment: tl;dr: status-bydesign

Comment: @ArtOfCode Does it happen for **all** the questions?

Comment: Yes, it's for all deleted questions that are also closed. So I take it that it **was** changed. Interesting.